# Mvc Core incorrect datetime format when controller is reading model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, asp.net-core

I have a date in my model and want it to be "dd.MM.yyyy" but when the controller parses the object it always reads it as "MM.dd.yyyy".

```
var supportedCulture = new CultureInfo("bg-BG");
        supportedCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            supportedCulture
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(supportedCulture),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
            FallBackToParentCultures = true,
            FallBackToParentUICultures = true,
            RequestCultureProviders = null
        });
        app.UseMvc();
```

This in my model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime AccidentDate { get; set; }
```

And this in my view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AccidentDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")
```

When I load the date into the page everything is correct but when I try to retrieve it it's always in the wrong format. I really can't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Please try if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37821420/1220550

Comment: It doesn't help. I have var asdd = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name; inside controller and <div>Current Culture: @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName</div>
<div>Current UI Culture: @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName</div> inside view and they both display the correct culture but the DateTime field keeps coming wrong